# Using webpack in Visual Studio's pre-build

Tags: c#, node.js, visual-studio, npm, webpack

I have two commands:

`npm run build` - calls `webpack` to compile all my .js

`npm run dev` - calls `webpack -w`, compiles all my .js and stays in watch mode, looking for changes.

I want to integrate it with Visual Studio's build, so I went into Properties -> Build Events -> Pre-build

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug (
  npm --prefix ../ run dev
) ELSE (
  npm --prefix ../ run build
)
```

This logic works. If I'm at release mode, it will simple bundle my files and the server will run. But the problem is at debug mode, since the `webpack -w` doesn't end, the build also never ends, it's expecting an exit code....

So I tried to outsmart Visual Studio and start a new cmd process that would not block the build's start:

`start cmd /K npm --prefix ../ run dev`

Unfortunately, Visual Studio is too smart for me.

So the question is: is there any smart way to make the visual studio simply run what I want in the pre-build command and not wait for it to finish?

I know there's a proper place for this called task runner, but I couldn't configure it properly, it doesn't recognize any commands from my package.json. Also, I don't want to active it manually after/before running my server, ideally I want it to be integrated with the server startup so that's why I went for the pre-build. But if there's a smarter way to do this, feel free to point it to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When in development environment, I believe that what you want is to run webpack when **running** the app, not when building. You can set a custom runner (instead of Chrome) and this runner is an executable that runs the browser and `webpack -w`

Comment: @SamirAguiar that seems...a better approach indeed. However I don't see any way to create a custom runner, would you mind pointing out to me how to do this?

Comment: Also, another thing that concerns me, is that I don't want anybody in my team having to manually configure this. I know the pre-build goes along with the .csproj that is in the repository that's why I was trying this.

Comment: See if [this extension and its linked blog post](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebPackTaskRunner) helps.

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured out a way to do this with a pre-build command. You can start webpack to the side at the same time you start your application in Visual Studio without waiting for the command to finish.

You can use

```
powershell start-process "cmd ""/K npm run start"""
```

For example, this is my pre-build event command line in Build Events under the ASP.Net MVC 5 Project's properties:

```
cd "$(ProjectDir)React"
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug (
  call npm run build-dev
  powershell start-process "cmd ""/K npm run start"""
)
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release (
  call npm run build-prod
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question:

> So the question is: is there any smart way to make the visual studio simply run what I want in the pre-build command and not wait for it to finish?

The answer is yes, there is a smart way that I figured out.

In your prebuild script, you need to use NodeJS to spawn a new process not connected to its parent. You would call something like this:

```sh
node spawner.js fork \"npm --prefix ../ run dev\"
```

Then you need the `spawner.js` script in your project root

```js
 /**
 * Spawns a new forked child process
 *
 * The process.argv property returns an array containing the command line arguments
 * passed when the Node.js process was launched. The first element will be process.execPath.
 * See process.argv0 if access to the original value of argv[0] is needed. The second element
 * will be the path to the JavaScript file being executed. The remaining elements will be any
 * additional command line arguments.
 * See: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv
 *
 */


/**
 * Function: run()
 * This method runs the command using child_proces.exec only
 * Does the same as function fork(), but in a different implementation.
 */
module.exports = {


   /**
    * Function: fork()
    * This method runs the command using child_proces.fork and child_process.exec
    * Does the same as function run(), but in a different implementation.
    * Forks a new NodeJS process of the same codebase in a new V8 instance.
    */
   fork: function (command) {

      console.log('Begin Forking New Process');
      console.log(command);

      var cp = require('child_process');
      var child = cp.fork('./forked-child.js', [command]);

      /**
       * child.unref()
       * Causes the parent's (this) event loop to not include the child (spawned-child.js)
       * in its reference count, allowing the parent to exit independently of the child,
       * unless there is an established IPC channel between the child and parent.
       */
      child.unref();

   },

   runTsNode: function (command) {

      console.log('Begin Running ts-node Script');

      require('child_process').exec(
         // terminating command prompt is /c - persistent command prompt is /k
         'ts-node ' + command + '"',
         function () {
            console.log('Received Command: ' + command);
         });

      /**
       * Debug the arguments received on command line.
       */
      var args = process.argv.slice(2);
      args.forEach((val, index) => {
         console.log(`${index}: ${val}`);
      });

      /**
       * Kill the child process after 2 seconds, once the detached cmd.exe process has spawned
       */
      setTimeout(function () {
         console.log('Done Spawning');
         process.exit(0);
      }, 2000);

   },

   runNode: function (command) {

      console.log('Begin Running Node Script');

      require('child_process').exec(
         // terminating command prompt is /c - persistent command prompt is /k
         'node ' + command + '"',
         function () {
            console.log('Received Command: ' + command);
         });

      /**
       * Debug the arguments received on command line.
       */
      var args = process.argv.slice(2);
      args.forEach((val, index) => {
         console.log(`${index}: ${val}`);
      });

      /**
       * Kill the child process after 2 seconds, once the detached cmd.exe process has spawned
       */
      setTimeout(function () {
         console.log('Done Spawning');
         process.exit(0);
      }, 2000);

   },

   runCommand: function (command) {

      console.log('Begin Running Command Line Script');

      require('child_process').exec(
         // terminating command prompt is /c - persistent command prompt is /k
         'cmd.exe @cmd /k "' + command + '"',
         function () {
            console.log('Received Command: ' + command);
         });

      /**
       * Debug the arguments received on command line.
       */
      var args = process.argv.slice(2);
      args.forEach((val, index) => {
         console.log(`${index}: ${val}`);
      });

      /**
       * Kill the child process after 2 seconds, once the detached cmd.exe process has spawned
       */
      setTimeout(function () {
         console.log('Done Spawning');
         process.exit(0);
      }, 2000);

   },


};

require('make-runnable'); // must be at the END of the file
```

It requires `make-runnable` so make sure to run `npm i make-runnable -D`

Along with `spawner.js`, this script uses `forked-child.js` which should also be placed in your project root.

```js
 /**
 * Spawns a new forked child process
 *
 * The process.argv property returns an array containing the command line arguments
 * passed when the Node.js process was launched. The first element will be process.execPath.
 * See process.argv0 if access to the original value of argv[0] is needed. The second element
 * will be the path to the JavaScript file being executed. The remaining elements will be any
 * additional command line arguments.
 * See: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv
 *
 */

// Window only until its updated for cross platform
require('child_process')
// terminating command prompt is /c - persistent command prompt is /k
   .exec('start cmd.exe @cmd /k "' + process.argv[2] + '"',
      function () {
         console.log('Received Command: ' + process.argv[2]);
      });


/**
 * Debug the arguments received on command line.
 */
process.argv.forEach((val, index) => {
   console.log(`${index}: ${val}`);
});

/**
 * Kill the child process after 2 seconds, once the detached cmd.exe process has spawned
 */
setTimeout(function () {
   console.log('Done Spawning');
   process.exit(0);
}, 2000);
```

I have included other methods in the spanwer.js script that might come in useful. For this example it's calling the `fork` method.

Now just run your build, and it should execute

1. `node spawner.js fork \"npm --prefix ../ run dev\"`,  which calls
2. `forked-child.js`, which receives your command as an argument and
3. opens that in a new detached process

Because it is detached from its parent via forking, Visual Studio's build process will continue running even while this runs in its own never-ending terminal instance.

So that is how I solved this exact problem with webpack-dev-server and visual studio. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently had a similar situation where I want to run Webpack in watch mode after building my project in debug mode.  I was running into the same issue where the prebuild step would hang indefinitely when I ran my project.

I came up with the following solution which runs the .bat file by opening a separate cmd window which doesn't stop the build from completing and works like a charm.

**Step 1** - Create a .bat file in the root of the project, I have called this WebpackWatch.bat with the following code, this will run webpack and put it into watch mode in the opened cmd window

```
webpack --progress --profile --watch --mode development
```

**Step 2** - In the post build event, I have added the following, this will run the powershell command to open the .bat file, and then continue on with the build, for release mode, it calls the script build:prod in my packages config

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug powershell start-process $(ProjectDir)WebpackWatch.bat
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release npm run build:prod
```

For information purposes my package.json file has the following script for the release build event, notice this does not have --watch in the build process so this completes file with the build step.

```
 "scripts": {
    "build:prod": "webpack --progress --profile --mode production"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

cd [The Path Of WebPack Package.json base on bin folder]
npx webpack